# Best method for setting permanent aliases in powershell?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, powershell, alias, winget

When I install something like `ffmpeg` with `winget`, it sets permanent aliases for `ffmpeg`, `ffplay`, & `ffprobe`.

```
winget install gyan.ffmpeg
```

It doesn't look like it's adding anything to my path environment variable. If I use the `Set-Alias` PowerShell utility, said alias is ephemeral, only lasting until the end of the current session. Eventually, I found that I can use my `$profile` to denote a list of aliases that instantiate every time I launch my shell.

Does winget do the same thing just with a different "profile" file? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: To find out what a command is or where it is located, use the `Get-Command` cmdlet. This way, you will also be able to find the files WinGet creates.

Comment: Setting aliases within `$env:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` would be a way to make them permanent _([example](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/Powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1) lines 76 - 77 or via variables starting line 112)_

Comment: Those are "Portable Links" in WinGet parlance. Look for "Portable Links Directory" in the output of `winget --info`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because WinGet is *not* PowerShell-specific, it cannot rely on PowerShell stuff. Instead, it *does* add to `%PATH%` (once). It also shows a message when it does this. If you did not see the message, it may have already modified `%PATH%` in the past. WinGet adds `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WinGet\Links\` (in its expanded form) to your user’s `%PATH%` (not the system-wide one).

WinGet creates symlinks in this folder. These are then usable from any shell or *Run* prompt.

In my opinion, yes, this method is superior, because it is effective everywhere.

However, it only works with `.exe` files. If you need PowerShell-specific aliases (involving cmdlets or whatever), you must use PowerShell methods to create them permanently. `$profile` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

From the post
[How to create permanent PowerShell Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914589/how-to-create-permanent-powershell-aliases),
I quote the excellent
[answer by Naigel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914795/165358) :

> It's possible to store in a `profile.ps1` file any PowerShell code to
> be executed each time PowerShell starts. There are at least [6
> different
> paths](https://web.archive.org/web/20121105003839/http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx)
> where to store the code depending on which user has to execute it. We
> will consider only 2 of them: the "all users" and the "only your user"
> paths (follow the previous link for further options).
>
> To answer your question, you only have to create a `profile.ps1` file
> containing the code you want to be executed, that is:
>
> ```
> New-Alias Goto Set-Location
> ```
>
> and save it in the proper path:
>
> - `"$Home\Documents"` (usually `C:\Users\<yourname>\Documents`): only your user will execute the code. This is the recommended location *You
>   can quickly find your profile location by running `echo $profile` in
>   PowerShell*
> - `$PsHome` (`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`): every user will execute this code
>
> **IMPORTANT**: remember you need to restart your PowerShell instances to apply the changes.
>
> **TIPS**
>
> - If both paths contain a `profile.ps1` file, the all-users one is executed first, then the user-specific one. This means the
>   user-specific commands will overwrite variables in case of duplicates
>   or conflicts.
> - Always put the code in the user-specific profile if there is no need to extend its execution to every user. This is safer because you don't
>   pollute other users' space (usually, you don't want to do that).
> - Another advantage is that you don't need administrator rights to add the file to your user-space (you do for anything in
>   C:\Windows\System32).
> - If you really need to execute the profile code for every user, mind that the $PsHome path is different for 32bit and 64bit instances of
>   PowerShell. You should consider both environments if you want to
>   **always** execute the profile code.
>
>   The paths are:
> - `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` for the 64bit environment
> - `C:\Windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` for the 32bit one (Yeah I know, the folder naming is counter-intuitive, but [it's
>   correct](https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/)).

Answer (score 0):

No, cmdlets like winget and other powershell modules install themselves inside your powershell modules folder. After you run `import-module <name>` that module's commands can now be used. Commands are just functions.

To find out where your modules are stored, run the following command in powershell: `write-host $env:PSModulePath`

If you want to replicate the same as winget, create a new powershell script, place the following inside:

```
function MyFunction()
{
    write-host "MyFunction was executed."
}
```

And save this in the path found before as a `*.psm1` file where the * is replaced with anything you desire of course.

I haven't found the need to actually write my own modules and I did end up just creating the functions inside my profile.ps1, so I'm not entirely sure what the location is to auto-load your modules, and if you need to add a .psd1 file next to the module for it to work.

This answer is just for you to know how else to do it, if using a profile.ps1 is out of the question.